# Virtualbox accessing HTML file on shared folder

Tags: html, css, windows, internet-explorer, virtualbox

I am making a website using the usual CSS and HTML but need to make sure it works in different versions of IE.

I have installed Windows 7 using Virtualbox on my Mac. I then put the files in a shared folder that both my Mac and Windows can access together. On Windows I can access the HTML file if I use Chrome but in IE I get the generic `This page can't be displayed` error.

The only solution that works is manually, every time copying the files to the desktop on Windows.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: you should go throug a local server , like xampp (or alike and easy to set), then you can access it from any virtualbox image running. It is even better to do it this way, some version of IE do not behave the same if it  access a file from a folder or from a (local) server . best is to set local server from the main OS running (not within virtualbox image)

Comment: So if I have XAMPP on my mac and type localhost on Windows how will it know what that means?

Comment: My english is not that good, so here is a link http://justinmarsan.com/accessing-localhost-in-mac-osx-from-windows-vm-in-virtualbox/ . basicly, http://localhost/ works from the OS where the server is running. to access it from somewhere else, you need to retrieve the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I had to use a local server on my Mac OS -XAMPP.

What I did was went to `VirtuaBox VM > Preferences > Network > Added a new NAT network` then typed in `http://10.0.2.2` and the localhost came up successfully. Now I can test my websites on Internet Explorer in Windows 7 using the VirtualBox VM and other browsers on my Mac OS host system.